# Suitecrm seperate create/new view

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

**Some information beforehand:**
I'm using SuiteCRM Version 7.9.6
Sugar Version 6.5.25 (Build 344)

**My issue:**
I have some customCode in place in my AOS_Contracts editview that block a few input fields I don't want the user to be able to touch (edit).

Sadly, the editview is being shared with the "Create Contract" screen too. This means that when you want to create a contract, you see the exact same view as the editview, meaning that some of the input fields are blocked. However, for this "createview" I want all of the inputs to be enabled.
In fact I might want to use a seperate view all together.

**My question:**
I'm wondering, how can I implement a new view (createView or something) to the AOS_Contracts module? Or if you know a better approach for within the editView thats welcome too.

I've been searching through here, google and their official docs but I just can't find it.

Comment: can you share code for this section : Sadly, the editview is being shared with the "Create Contract" screen too.

Comment: Not knowing anything about those applications, do you know (in code) whether the screen is in "edit" or "create" mode?

Comment: I appreciate the help of you two but I can guarantee that you really need SuiteCRM knowledge for this issue. The solution isn't within the view code, you need to do several things with hooks and other classes which I don't know the process of (not for 7.9.6)

Comment: Looking for something like this?

Comment: It is simple one if I understood your scenario well. You want to enable all the inputs in create view but not in an edit view. You can write your logic on `view.edit.php` file that it is "Editing" an existing record or "Creating" a new record. I mean if record id is present on editview or not. Use this logic and you can enable/disable any field you want.